# VueJS Frontend / Admin Screens

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

We have built a frontend ecommerce application using vue. But not we are getting ready to tackle the backend/admin screens for this app. The admins screens will control a lot of things on the frontend of this.

So my question is do you build 2 independent applications for this or do you build them both in the same structure. If you are building them all within the same structure what does main.js and app.vue look like then? Would you have a simple boolean on the parent div that is for the frontend and then the backend? These are going to look totally different obviously, they may have a few shared components between the frontend and admin screens though.

Using the Router seems easy enough for directing the user to the right files, but it is how to start is what I am having trouble with since the entry point is app.vue and main.js.

Any advice here would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your case the word backend is not appropriate. You speak of 2 front-ends, one of which is reserved for admins.

The difference between the two fronts should guide you in your choice of separating it into 2 projects or managing the separation with the router and a permissions system.

If complex components are in common, then you should probably be working on a single project. If you want to adopt a different page structure then maybe 2 separate projects will work best.

Here is an example of a router based on role authorization

https://codesandbox.io/s/k5kp135z95?file=/_helpers/router.js

```js
export const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: HomePage,
      meta: { authorize: [] }
    },
    {
      path: "/admin",
      component: AdminPage,
      meta: { authorize: [Role.Admin] }
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      component: LoginPage
    },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: "*", redirect: "/" }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const { authorize } = to.meta;
  const currentUser = authenticationService.currentUserValue;

  if (authorize) {
    if (!currentUser) {
      // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
      return next({ path: "/login", query: { returnUrl: to.path } });
    }

    // check if route is restricted by role
    if (authorize.length && !authorize.includes(currentUser.role)) {
      // role not authorised so redirect to home page
      return next({ path: "/" });
    }
  }

  next();
});
```